# Can I have multiple components attached to one class object in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have two different templates and styling for an input box, but they basically function the same way and access the back-end data the same way. I would like the two templates to access the same functions. Is there a way to attach 2 components to one class or allow one component to access the other's functions?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'inputbox1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/Tnputbox1.html'
})
export class Inputbox1 { 
...
}
```

The other option is to create two classes that have identical code for each component, or rewrite all the templates and styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an Abstract Class and extend it for other classes :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'inputbox1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/Tnputbox1.html'
})
export class Inputbox1 extends Inputbox { 
...
}

@Component({
    selector: 'inputbox2',
    templateUrl: 'templates/Tnputbox2.html'
})
export class Inputbox2 extends Inputbox { 
...
}

abstract class Inputbox { 
...your common functions
}
```

Comment: Would that make it possible to switch the template for a given component instance back and forth without losing its state? I'd like to have a single object with an editable view and a read-only view that users can toggle between.

Comment: I just discovered that you need to put the abstract class declaration before the others or you will get "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(…)"